# cannot click with the cursor on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, cursor

This happend when I did something:

[image: hck]

I could then only write commands, make shortcuts and move the cursor(cannot click on anything).

I rebooted then and the problem was solved.

Why did it happend and are it better ways to solve it?

UPDATE:

input:

```
xkill
```

output:

```
Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....
xkill: unable to grab cursor
```

Comment: Can be a bug or something. Did this happened many times or just once. If it is more than one, can you try `clear` command when this happens in terminal once.

Comment: It happend only one time.

Comment: Just submit a bug report. If they found it true then the bug will be removed in ther next version and have a good time:))

Comment: Now it happends twice.

Comment: And it is not because screensot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291732/authentication-required-window-stuck-after-login) that I asked there was an answer that said:

> I faced the same problem on Pop_!OS, no need to reboot actually;
>
> The easier way is to just restart GNOME by one of two ways:
>
> - pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or
> - in terminal, `killall -3 gnome-shell`
>
> This should just restart Gnome Shell. You will not lose your open windows, but you should be reminded to save all your work >regularly!
>
> Related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1824874

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291732/authentication-required-window-stuck-after-login/1291922#1291922)

The answer works in this question too.
Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: The answer worked, but I have a second question: Why did it happened?

Comment: @mansojang1024, I don't know why, sometimes it just happends for me.

Answer (score 0):

I the solved same problem this way:

1. I opened the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. I found Nautilus's PID:

   ```
   ps ax | grep /usr/bin/nautilus
   ```
3. I killed the process using the `kill` command:

   ```
   kill 1234
   ```

   where `1234` is the PID I found with the previous command.

As a one-line command:

```
kill $( ps ax | grep /usr/bin/nautilus )
```